# plain javaScript get attribute in function from event listener

Tags: javascript, html, console, event-listener, getattribute

So I am trying to figure out how to get the data id value from a groups of links that share the same class name. For example the links appear in this markup

```
<td><a class="deleteLink" href="#" data-id="4">&#10005;</a></td>
<td><a class="deleteLink" href="#" data-id="7">&#10005;</a></td>
```

then I've got some javascript that creates event listeners. For some reason in the console I get an error saying "**Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function**"

```
function deleteUser(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var userId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')){
        window.location.href = 'delete.php?id=' + userId;
    }
}

var deleteLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('deleteLink');

for (i = 0; i < deleteLinks.length; i++) {
    addEventListener('click',deleteUser,false);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be? Where you are using it, `this` refers to the function.

Comment: Shouldn't this be the A tag that was clicked? How do I get the data-id value?

Comment: Try [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)?

Comment: The answer is to make it this.target instead, as this will probably refer to the body/page itself. this.target will make it refer to the element that actually owns the event. For future reference, you should do alert(this) to troubleshoot. Sorry, I meant event.target as Sumner Evans stated. Also, check the solution that drooh added

Comment: Should be getting error that `addEventListener` isn't a function. If used properly the handler should work fine

Comment: That `EventListener` in your loop is attached to `window`. You want to attach the `listener` like `deleteLinks[i].addEventListener`... yet still, `i` would be at the end of the loop by the time the `click` happened, without making it a `let`. Also, `.getElementsByClassName` may be something you want to avoid, as it returns a live collection. I advise using `const deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.deletLink')`... it will save you headaches.

Answer (score 0):

forgot to attach the listener properly, should be

```
deleteLinks[i].addEventListener('click',deleteUser,false);
```

Complete answer using **querySelectorAll** instead of **getElementsByClassName**

```
function deleteUser(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var userId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?')){
        window.location.href = 'delete.php?id=' + userId;
    }
}

var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteLink'); 

for (i = 0; i < deleteLinks.length; i++) {
    deleteLinks[i].addEventListener('click',deleteUser,false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var userId = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target